# The dropdown menu does not appear correctly

Tags: html, css, web

I made this page

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navbar */

nav {
 background: #4D636F;
 max-height: 51px;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
}

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav span.badge {
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 12px;
 top: 5px;
 right: 6;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 padding: 1px 4px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

nav .logo {
 background: #3A4B53;
 float: left;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 12px 18px;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}

nav .logo i {
 margin-right: 13px;
}

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 12px;
}

nav ul li {
 display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 12px 18px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #444;
 background-color: white;
}

nav .right {
 float: right;
}

nav .right a img {
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}

li.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 padding: 0;
 top: 20px;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.dropdown-menu a {
 color: #444;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

/* Navbar ends */
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="myNav">
 <div class="logo">
  <span><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Logo</span>
 </div>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" style="position: relative;"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
    <span class="badge">3</span>
   </a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <a href="#">One</a>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="right"><a href="#"><img src="images/profile.png" align="middle"></a></li>
 </ul>

</nav>
```

The problem as viewed is that the dropdown-menu does not appear correctly.
I made it it absolute and it has z-index : 1 :(

I know that I didn't make it hoverable but I want it to appear then I will handle it.

I don't feel anything wrong with the code, but the output says otherwise.

What I did wrong? And what should I do to make it right?

Comment: The problem is with the `overflow: hidden;` property on the `.nav` class in your CSS, which makes anything that overflows the nav's bounds be hidden.

Comment: look at this http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

nav has overflow hidden as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `overflow: hidden` in the nav

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navbar */

nav {
 background: #4D636F;
 max-height: 71px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav span.badge {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 12px;
 top: -11px;
    height: 15px;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 padding: 2px 6px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

nav .logo {
 background: #3A4B53;
 float: left;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 12px 18px;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}

nav .logo i {
 margin-right: 13px;
}

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
    line-height: 45px
}

nav ul li {
 display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 12px 18px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #444;
 background-color: white;
}

nav .right {
 float: right;
}

nav .right a img {
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}

li.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 padding: 0;
 top: 31px;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.dropdown-menu a {
 color: #444;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

/* Navbar ends */
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="myNav">
 <div class="logo">
  <span><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Logo</span>
 </div>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" style="position: relative;"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
    <span class="badge">3</span>
   </a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <a href="#">One</a>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="right"><a href="#"><img src="images/profile.png" align="middle"></a></li>
 </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: try to remove it.. nav sucks :(

Answer (score -1):

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 31px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-height: 71px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.dropdown-menu :hover {
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I used that a couple of times on my web page.